# Как сделать воспроизведение случайного видео на странице без повторения?

Tags: видео, генерация-случайных-данных

Я уже сделал, что бы видео случайно воспроизводилось, но мне нужно, что бы оно не повторялось.
Вот код

```
function refreshbutton(){
var count = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
document.getElementsByTagName('source')[0].src = "./video/" + videos[count];video.load();}
var videos= ["video1.mp4","video2.mp4","video3.mp4"];
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Очевидно же - запоминать то что уже показывали, и проверять при воспроизведении следующего файла что он еще не воспроизводился, или не очень очевидно ?)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, очевидно, но код с этим действием я не в силе написать